# What is the best way for sorting date (string type)?

Tags: c++, linux, date, sorting

I get a date by executing `ls -al` command.

e.g:

```
Aug 5 11:56
Jul 14 09:31
```

I can't add option for sorting this information.

In this situation. Is this the best way?

1. convert

   ```
   Aug 5 11:56 -> 08051156
   Jul 14 09:31 -> 07140931
   ```
2. sorting

   ```
   07140931
   08051105
   ```

Comment: The best way is to have your date strings in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: Why don't use `ls -ltr`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you using `ls` rather than the c++ file listing APIs?

Answer (score 4):

None of your solutions work. I don't even know where you get `1105` from `11:56`. The way to sort date time as strings is to use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). But why on earth do you use `ls -al` to get date in C++? You should call [`stat()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to get file information and it'll return the [`struct timespec`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/timespec) that you can use to sort directly as numbers, no need to deal with strings

Since C++17 you can just use [`std::filesystem::last_write_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) and other types of time in `std::filesystem` directly and sort

Even if you get time from the command line then it's better to use the [`stat` command](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to get date as ISO-8601

Comment: Of course, given the amount of code provided in the question -- it's not entirely clear where C++ fits into the problem other than the tag...  You've covered the pieces as well as anyone could.